# Android GridView reorder elements via Drag and Drop

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop

I have a GridView in an application I am working on. I would like to be able to reorder the items in the GridView via drag-and-drop. I have found lots of help for ListViews but nothing on GridViews. I want to achieve behaviour like in this launcher app http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5LISE8BU_E&t=5m30s. Any ideas?

Comment: hey did you solved this, I have a similar problem to solve. Can you please share some code snippet?

Comment: Chandra, if it's still needed, please look at my answer below.

Comment: Can you mark one of them as answer? That will help lot of people who are looking for help to quickly find the answer.

Answer (score 24):

If you don't resolve this problem I will provide my code. But it works on Android 3.0 and above, because I use [android drag-n-drop framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

```
grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
grid.setAdapter(new DragGridAdapter(items, getActivity()));

....

grid.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                GridView parent = (GridView) v;

                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                int position = parent.pointToPosition(x, y);
                if (position > AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {

                    int count = parent.getChildCount();
                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        View curr = parent.getChildAt(i);
                        curr.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

                            @Override
                            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

                                boolean result = true;
                                int action = event.getAction();
                                switch (action) {
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                                    break;
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                                    break;
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_image_view_small_gallery_selected);
                                    break;
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_image_view_small_gallery_unselected);
                                    break;
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                                    if (event.getLocalState() == v) {
                                        result = false;
                                    } else {
                                        View droped = (View) event.getLocalState();
                                        GridItem dropItem = ((DragGridItemHolder) droped.getTag()).item;

                                        GridView parent = (GridView) droped.getParent();
                                        DragGridAdapter adapter = (DragGridAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
                                        List<GridItem> items = adapter.getItems();

                                        View target = v;
                                        GridItem targetItem = ((DragGridItemHolder) target.getTag()).item;
                                        int index = items.indexOf(targetItem);
                                        items.remove(dropItem);
                                        items.add(index, dropItem);
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_image_view_small_gallery_unselected);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    result = false;
                                    break;
                                }
                                return result;
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    int relativePosition = position - parent.getFirstVisiblePosition();


                    View target = (View) parent.getChildAt(relativePosition);

                    DragGridItemHolder holder = (DragGridItemHolder) target.getTag();
                    GridItem currentItem = holder.item;
                    String text = currentItem.getFile().getAbsolutePath();

                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("DragData", text);
                    target.startDrag(data, new View.DragShadowBuilder(target), target, 0);
                }
            }
            return false;
```

and DragGridAdapter

```
public class DragGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context context;
private List<GridItem> items;

public DragGridAdapter(List<GridItem> items, Context context){
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    DragGridItemHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new DragGridItemHolder();

        ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
        holder.image = img;
        convertView = img;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (DragGridItemHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.item = items.get(position);
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(items.get(position).getBitmap());
    return convertView;
}

public List<GridItem> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

I hope it helps to you

Comment: View.OnDragListener is the part of Android-3.0, Above code is not working

Comment: thnx for the example.. I got only got one bug.. The first time i drag a item over other items in the gridview, the imageview sources of the items are lost. When i drop it the sources wil be fixed.. After the first drag and drop of a activity everything works perfectly.. Any idea for the strange behaviour of this?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have answer for your question. Maybe it is a bug on your's device

Comment: @Dmitriy_Boichenko .I like your code but it would be even more better if you  give the code for DragGridItemHolder

Comment: @Abhilash Unfortunatelly I don't have this code today. But as I remember it's simple. Please consider standard android's viewholder pattern

Comment: @Dmitriy_Boichenko ,thanks for this reply to my late comment,I got it now ,it was just a view holder pattern afterall,missed that point entirely .

Comment: but how do you make it draggable only after a long click on the gridview item

Answer (score 7):

My version for drag and drop grid view https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid.
It's extends original GridView, supports drag and drop to reorder items, auto-scroll if drag out of screen. It's completely functional on 3.0+ api, but supports 2.2 and 2.3 with limitations (no animations).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to edit, but you seem to have missed the point a bit. This is still basically a link-only answer; such answers are discouraged. There are two main reasons for this: it's usually much more helpful to answer users' specific issues directly, and even links to good resources sometimes go bad. Please see [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for more detail.

Comment: Alex, your grid is not working well for two columns, specially while dragging from bottom to top. Can you please help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at thquinn's [DraggableGridView](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView), This was developed targeting Android 2.2 (API level 8).
Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: This is cool solution. But it don't have any scroll listeners. So if you have a lot of pictures you can take Out Of Memory Error

Comment: It's not an AdapterView, so no view recycling is implemented

Answer (score 2):

Google recently released a few code labs a few months back. 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-adaptive-layouts/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#0

You can check the solution to it here
https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals-apps-v2/tree/master/MaterialMe-Resource

They make grid layout with movable cards that can be dragged and dropped anywhere in the layout using the itemTouchHandler.

The more detailed code on how to do the drag and drop is [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-training-cards-and-colors/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#4)
You need to look into the ***Task 3: Make your CardView swipeable, movable, and clickable*** section

Answer (score 1):

Using the drag-n-drop framework, instead that cycling the childs and setting the draglistener, I use as a grid item layout container, a DragableLinearLayout that extends the LinearLayout and implements the onDragEvent(DragEvent) method.

So you can fill your grid with the adapter as usual and most of the drag and drop code is on the onDragEvent of DragableLinearLayout

```
public class DragableLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {


    public DragableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
            int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public DragableLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public DragableLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDragEvent(DragEvent event) {
        //in wich grid item am I?
        GridView parent = (GridView) getParent();
        Object item = parent.getAdapter().getItem(
                parent.getPositionForView(this));
            //if you need the database id of your item...
        Cursor cur = (Cursor) item;
        long l_id = cur.getLong(cur.getColumnIndex("youritemid"));

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

            setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            invalidate();
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            invalidate();
            return false;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
ClipData cd = event.getClipData();
            long l_id_start = Long.valueOf(cd.getItemAt(0).getText()
                    .toString());
            //
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "DROP FROM " + l_id_start
                    + " TO " + l_id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //do your stuff  
                    ........
                    //the db requery will be on the onDragEvent.drop of the container
                    //see the listener


            return false;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            invalidate();
            //
            return false;

        }

        return true;

    }


}



private View.OnDragListener listenerOnDragEvent = new View.OnDragListener() {

    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        // Defines a variable to store the action type for the incoming
        // event
        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            // REQUERY
            updateDbView();
            return false;
            // break;

        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently found a solution on which its author spent quite some time here http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/03/03/improved-drag-drop-for-gridview/
There are 4 previous related blog posts explaining what is going on in more detail there.

Answer (score 0):

Probably PagedDragDropGrid project is what you need: https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid

It provides custom `ViewGroup` (similar to GridView) with feature of smooth reordering (exactly like in your video). Probably it'll require a bit of customizations, but it's worth.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: in the above library, I am not able to scroll in vertical direction when i'm dragging... any other options??

Comment: Yeah, you should a bit customize it if you want scrolling. Try to implement ScrollView with DragDropGrid (not PagedDragDropGrid) inside, it helped me. Sorry, I have no time right now to find exact solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [library](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview) from h6ah4i that takes advantage of the Recycler Views to offer a drag and drop gridview with reorder capabilities.