# Android Gridview drag and drop example

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android GridView reorder elements via Drag and Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146639/android-gridview-reorder-elements-via-drag-and-drop)

Can anyone give me some link from where I can learn Drag and Drop inside Android GridView.

Comment: Maybe it helps to you: [Another drag-n-drop question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146639/android-gridview-reorder-elements-via-drag-and-drop/7413757#7413757

Comment: You asked for a link, here is a link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4yktX3SWSs . Source code link on Google code, posted under video, in description.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For drag and drop icons in grid view,

you can refer following tutorial...

It is very helpful for it.

[Drag-Drop for an Android GridView](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/)

Comment: [Thia is a good example](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/moving-views-part-3/) but we are force to use itemcell, @Chirag_CID how to implement the drag and drop in gridview item which gridview which are already filled and there a drop zone where you drop your files

Comment: late answer, but for drop zone this might help: http://code.google.com/p/android-gridview-drag-and-drop/ , but you might need to modify the code according to your needs, as this drop zone deletes the item dropped into it.

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the party, here, but you might be able to use a library I wrote for android called DraggableGridView:

https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

It's an extension of ViewGroup. Long click to drag, includes animation, etc.